# Sequential execution in javascript over network

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my application, a recursive function calls a remote peer for some data and then calls itself again. Is there any way to wait for response from the server and then continue the flow of execution?

I am using `Simple-Peer` for remote calls.

```
function foo() {
    data = getFromPeer();
    if(condition)
        foo();
    else return bar;
}
```

`getFromPeer` is a user-defined function which sends data to a remote peer using a `SimplePeer` connection. The remote peer responds back when it receives the request. There are no promises or callbacks defined as of now.

Comment: Can you please share it?

Comment: Since we don't know your getFromPeer() function, Best I can think of is, set a default value of data. run a loop and wait until its value changes or a expected value comes. Be aware to put a maximum wait. Otherwise, It can stuck forever.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation of https://github.com/feross/simple-peer, there does not seem to be a standard way of doing "Remote Procedure Calls" or receiving an ACKnowledgement of the fact that some data that was previously sent was actually received.

So in order to achieve what you want to achieve with simple-peer you need to add a custom "protocol" over the simple-peer channel. Since you have no guarantee over the order in which the remote peer will receive your messages, you need to give an ID to each message.

something like this in pseudo code (and considering that `peer` is a connected simple-peer)

```
pendingJobs = {}
function addJob(data, callback) {
    var id = uuid() // imagine a function giving a uuid
    pendingJobs[id] = callback
    peer.send({ id: uuid, payload: data })
}
peer.on('data', function(info) {
    var id = info.id
    var cb;
    if (pendingJobs[id] && info.payload) {
        cb = pendingJobs[id]
        cb(info.payload)
    }
})
```

Of course this pseudo-code solution is very rough, and you would probably need to add some garbage collection of pendingJobs, have error callbacks in case the remote peer never sends the ACK message.

you could add a type for each message ('rpc', 'ack', ..)